# C# - Prevent Windows 10 from resizing Form Window

Tags: c#, winforms

How can you prevent Windows 10 from re-scaling your form windows? It is pretty annoying because the values that I select in the designer are different from what the outcome is.
*(I am sorry that this question is so shortly-written and not doesnt have alot of information)*

Comment: It doesn't re-scale for me?

Comment: You need declare your app [to be dpiAware](http://stackoverflow.com/a/13228495/17034).  Otherwise a preview of what will happen when your app runs on a machine with a low resolution monitor.

Comment: I agree with Hans that _part_ of your issue will be addressed by following the advice in the marked duplicate. Note, however, that Winforms itself does not scale well according to DPI. Even in a "dpi-aware" program, you may still have problems with layout as you adjust the size of things in the program. There are other duplicate questions on Stack Overflow to address that part of the question.

Comment: @HansPassant Well, my problem isnt solved though. This only solved the blurry fonts, the main problem is unsolved, though the coordinates of pictureboxes still differ. In the designer {Width=800, Height=600}, in the resulting output {Width=602, Height=488}